# Access to DialectResolutionInfo and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

**hibernate.cfg.xml:** https://pastebin.com/NZ6b34NH

**Stack trace:** https://pastebin.com/2LieW5RT

The problem seems to be here:

```
`Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`
```

But I did set the dialect:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
```

Anyway, I can't interpret this message. It seems not about the dialect property.

By the way, this is tutorial on Hibernate from here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-helpers

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial is outdated. Look at [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial-configuration-dialect).
Try to use the below config:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        
        <!-- Show and print nice SQL on stdout -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

If this is not legacy project I also would suggest to use mapping based on annotation.

Comment: Thak you. But now I have this error: https://pastebin.com/74tqh7y5